# Weird model stretching

Tags: modeling

[image]

Hi all, There's this strange shading bug on the wings of a plane that I'm making.
How can I solve this? I've tried adding more geometry, but to no avail. It's starting to annoy me greatly.

Thanks, 
Sisyphus

Edit: I've mostly fixed the problem now, but there is still a persisting little spot. Here's a wireframe of my model.
[image]

Comment: Select the face and press ctrl+N to flip normals

Comment: @ateks this helped greatly, but there is still a small little spot where the shading is glitching out.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add an image of the model in wireframe and edit mode in face select mode. That way we can see the topology of your object.

Comment: @cegaton Done. I've mostly fixed the problem with the normals though.